# gmaps4rails: How to retrieve json value from the controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, json, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I've got a `shop` model. I would like to output a simple alert box that displays a `shop` name using javascript when I click on a marker of a shop on the map.

This is my code:

```
# controller
@json = Shop.all.to_gmaps4rails do |shop, marker|
  marker.json({ id: shop.id, name: shop.name })
end

# view
<%= gmaps("map_options" => { auto_zoom: false, zoom: 2, class: "homepage-map" },
      "markers" => { data: @json,
                     options: { do_clustering: true,
                                clusterer_maxZoom: 11,
                                raw: "{ animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP }" }
                    })
%>

<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <  this.markers.length; ++i) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map.markers[i].serviceObject, 'click', function() {
      alert(put something here);
    });
  }
};
</script>
<% end %>
```

This is my first time dealing with json so I've read some introductory articles on json and also [json in javascript](http://www.json.org/js.html). I was wondering how this is done with gmaps4rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function handleMarkerClickClosure(marker) {
  return function() {
    alert(marker.name);
  }
}

Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i <  this.markers.length; ++i) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps.map.markers[i].serviceObject, 'click', handleMarkerClickClosure(Gmaps.map.markers[i]) );
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works! However if I do something a bit complicated like showing all the dresses that belong to a shop, it runs sql `SELECT` statement for every shop during page load, making it unscalable. I could load only certain markers when user finished zooming but this strategy doesn't work if I want to show the whole world at zoom level 2. Do you have any general advice for this?